# en mysql es posible referencia dos tablas a un campo?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

estoy tratando de hacer un sistema para registrar clientes y sus compras.

el problema que tengo es que hay dos tipos de producto, productos_propios y productos_reventa, y quiero que en detalle pedido pueda tener un pk_producto que referencia a una u otra tabla según el tipo de producto, en este caso tabla detalle_pedido tendría un campo; tipo_producto ENUM('propio','recompra')

````
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS detalles_pedidos(
    pk_detalles_pedidos INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_pedido INT,
    fk_producto_propio INT,
    fk_producto_reventa INT,
    producto_tipo ENUM('propio','reventa') NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_producto_propio, producto_tipo) REFERENCES productos_propios(pk_producto_propio, 'propio') ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_producto_reventa, producto_tipo) REFERENCES productos_reventa(pk_producto_reventa, 'reventa') ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos_propios(
    pk_producto_propio INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_tamano INT,
    fk_producto INT,
    fk_cantidad INT,
    precio INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    unique (fk_tamano,precio),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_tamano) REFERENCES tamanos(pk_tamano),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_producto) REFERENCES productos(pk_producto),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_cantidad) REFERENCES cantidades(pk_cantidad)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos_reventa(
    pk_producto_reventa INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_tamano INT,
    fk_producto INT,
    precio_venta INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    precio_compra INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    referencia varchar(15) not null,
    unique (referencia,precio_venta),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_tamano) REFERENCES tamanos(pk_tamano),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_producto) REFERENCES productos(pk_producto)

);```
````

Comment: En primer lugar, las tablas de entidad deben ir primero en los `CREATE TABLE` o tendrás error, porque se intentará hacer referencia a ellas sin estar creadas. Dicho eso, ¿si tienes dos tablas, una para `productos_propios` y otra para `productos_reventa` y en `detalles_pedidos` tienes una llave foránea por cada tabla, con eso basta para la relación, no tienes que meter el `ENUM` en la restricción de llave foránea.

Comment: Bastaría con: `FOREIGN KEY (fk_producto_propio) REFERENCES productos_propios(pk_producto_propio) ON DELETE CASCADE,` y con `FOREIGN KEY (fk_producto_reventa) REFERENCES productos_reventa(pk_producto_reventa) ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: Además, las columnas que uses para la restricción de llave foránea **deben tener la misma definición que la columna en la tabla de referencia**. En `detalles_pedidos` debes definir `fk_producto_propio INT UNSIGNED,` y `fk_producto_reventa INT UNSIGNED,` porque en las tablas de referencia así están definidas las columnas relacionadas.

Comment: Querer meter un `ENUM` dentro de una restricción de llave foránea es un abuso de ese tipo de datos, [considerando todas las limitaciones que implica usar `ENUM` en ciertos casos](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/). Son sólo opiniones, y si quieres usar `ENUM` y te funciona bien, tienes todo el derecho de usarlo, pero NO para definir una FK. Además, es bueno saber que hay otras alternativas que, según la naturaleza de tu aplicación, podrían ser incluso mejores.

Comment: Sé que no tiene que ver exactamente con la pregunta, pero ¿Por qué dos tablas de productos?  Eso va complicar mucho más todo, por que no una sola tabla de productos, con los datos comunes, un tipo de producto y eventualmente tablas "satelites" para llevar los atributos propios de cada producto?